# Integrate Vue-CLI 3 with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4, vue-cli-3

Here the guide to develop with a Vue frontend

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/vuejs.html

But how to do it with a vue-cli 3 and Symfony 4?

SCENARIO

that's my configuration:

```
root
|-app (symfony)
|-frontend (a default vue cli config)
|-other (other dir)
```

Also a ***link*** would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 4 comes with Webpack Encore. Webpack Encore and Vue CLI are mutually exclusive. Both tools share the same goal of helping you manage your Webpack configuration but Vue CLI focus on Single Page Applications.

If you want to try using Vue CLI with Symfony, the files that you will need are inside the dist folder (in your case probably frontend/dist)